# HHL example solution on Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, hhl-algorithm

In the example on the Qiskit page (https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html#A.-Some-mathematical-background) section 3 for the HHL algorithm the author is trying to solve the system of equations written as $A \vec{x}=\vec{b}$, where:
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1 / 3 \\
-1 / 3 & 1
\end{array}\right), \quad \vec{b}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right) \quad \text { and } \quad \vec{x}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\
x_{2}
\end{array}\right).
$$

The final state of the system implementing the algorithm is:
$$
\frac{\frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}}\left|u_{1}\right\rangle+\frac{3}{4 \sqrt{2}}\left|u_{2}\right\rangle}{\sqrt{45 / 32}}=\frac{|x\rangle}{\|x\|}.
$$
Given that:
$$
|x\rangle={\frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}}\left|u_{1}\right\rangle+\frac{3}{4 \sqrt{2}}\left|u_{2}\right\rangle}
$$

where:
$$
\left|u_{1}\right\rangle=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-1
\end{array}\right) \quad \text { and } \quad\left|u_{2}\right\rangle=\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
1
\end{array}\right).
$$

How do i determine the solution to the system which is $\left[\begin{array}{ll}1.125 & 0.375\end{array}\right]$?